# Создание моделей по готовой базе для Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Решили перенести проект с самописной платформы на нормальную. Был выбран Laravel.

Но имеется уже не малая база с достаточным количеством таблиц.

Существует ли способ создания моделей для Eloquent по существующей базе? Или все нужно создавать руками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть на GitHub генератор моделей. Смотрите тут: [Model Generator](https://github.com/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator):

- `composer require ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator`
- добавляете в провайдеры `Iber\Generator\ModelGeneratorProvider`
- `php artisan make:models`
- удаляете всё, что сделали выше либо посмотрите документацию

Вот еще полезный компонент: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Может автоматически добавить аннотации для моделей (см. [Automatic phpDocs for models](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-for-models))

И улучшит поддержку в IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через Artisan создовать модели и контроллеры и многое другое!
Допустим

```
php artisan make:model User
```

это создаст модель

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'my_users';

}
```

[Документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

Есть другой вариант Онлайн рисуешь базу и скачиваешь папку уже с готовыми Контролерами, Моделями, Шаблонами и так далее [ссылка](http://www.laravelsd.com/)